Draw ellipses around a point and select an ellipse if they overlap
Here is some code to reproduce a data.frame containing projected coordinates and to add an ID column:
x <- c(611547.6411, 589547.6411, 611447.6411, 609847.6411, 606347.6411, 611447.6411, 613547.6411,642747.6411, 589647.6411, 606447.6411, 613547.6411, 640347.6411, 642847.6411, 612147.6411, 613847.6411, 640247.6411, 642947.6411, 584347.6411, 587747.6411, 606447.6411, 614247.6411, 640447.6411, 642747.6411, 584447.6411, 608647.6411, 612047.6411, 612747.6411,
613847.6411, 643147.6411, 583147.6411, 608747.6411, 611847.6411, 609647.6411, 610047.6411, 613747.6411, 586247.6411, 588647.6411, 643147.6411, 584347.6411, 606447.6411, 610147.6411, 613347.6411, 614647.6411, 586047.6411, 587247.6411, 611547.6411, 640347.6411, 643147.6411, 587147.6411, 583047.6411, 608747.6411, 612047.6411, 613947.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586847.6411, 611247.6411, 643247.6411, 587247.6411, 590347.6411, 582947.6411, 608947.6411, 611847.6411, 613447.6411, 614647.6411, 585147.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586947.6411, 611247.6411, 643047.6411, 587147.6411, 583947.6411, 587747.6411, 608547.6411, 611747.6411, 614047.6411, 585247.6411, 586247.6411, 588447.6411, 589147.6411, 611347.6411, 642447.6411, 586947.6411, 585847.6411, 587747.6411, 581447.6411, 612447.6411, 611947.6411, 600547.6411,
612047.6411, 610347.6411, 614147.6411, 582847.6411, 588547.6411, 589247.6411, 611247.6411, 638147.6411, 640547.6411, 642947.6411, 587047.6411, 585947.6411, 587647.6411, 600447.6411, 611347.6411, 612347.6411, 610347.6411, 587747.6411, 579747.6411, 583847.6411, 586847.6411, 588447.6411, 589347.6411, 643347.6411, 589347.6411, 586947.6411, 588247.6411, 588847.6411, 585847.6411, 590847.6411, 589447.6411, 590947.6411, 581347.6411, 611847.6411, 600647.6411, 610347.6411, 615947.6411, 613947.6411, 586347.6411, 579647.6411, 584047.6411, 586347.6411, 587747.6411, 587947.6411, 586547.6411, 587647.6411, 614047.6411, 643047.6411, 587947.6411, 585747.6411, 584947.6411, 600547.6411, 611947.6411, 606847.6411, 600847.6411, 612847.6411, 615747.6411, 620747.6411, 614047.6411, 632947.6411, 588147.6411, 579747.6411, 582747.6411)

y <- c(5272140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271640.5728, 5267440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271640.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277940.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268140.5728, 5268640.5728, 5271140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271340.5728, 5272240.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728,
5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5277340.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266840.5728, 5267240.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272140.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277140.5728, 5277240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277740.5728, 5277740.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278240.5728, 5278240.5728, 5264940.5728, 5265040.5728, 5265140.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267140.5728, 5267340.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268340.5728,
5271240.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271840.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5274340.5728, 5274440.5728, 5274640.5728, 5285140.5728, 5285240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277540.5728, 5277840.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266940.5728, 5268340.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5274540.5728, 5275040.5728, 5275340.5728, 5284840.5728, 5284940.5728, 5284940.5728, 5285040.5728, 5285040.5728)

# create the data frame
coordinates.df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# add an ID column and rearrange the columns
coordinates.df$ID <- 1:nrow(coordinates.df)
coordinates.df <- coordinates.df[c(3,1:2)]

Each pair of x and y is a geographic point. I would like to accomplish:

Draw an ellipse around each point. The main axis is supposed to be 700 m long, the minor axis 500 m. The orientation of all ellipses should be 225 degrees.

There will be overlaps of some ellipses. In case of overlaps, the ellipe with the lower or lowest ID value should be kept, while the others should be removed. So at the end there should be no overlapping ellipses.


EDIT: The Projected Coordinate System is ETRS 1989 UTM Zone 32N.

What if A:C have IDs 1:3, AB and BC intersect, but AC do not intersect? Keep A, or A and C? And how to handle many-to-many relationships? Maximise remaining ellipses at the expense of losing lower IDs?

@ L Tyrone: in that case, if A and C do not intersect, both should be kept. Here it is most important that as many low IDs as possible remain.

sfdep::st_ellipse() and a simple iteration should help here.
Create ellipses
coordinates.sf$E = sf::st_geometry(coordinates.sf) |>
  lapply(\(i) sfdep::st_ellipse(geometry=i, sx=1400L, sy=1000L, rotation=225L, n=100L) |> 
           sf::st_sf() |> sf::st_cast("POLYGON")) |> 
  do.call(what="rbind") |> 
  sf::`st_geometry<-`("geometryE") |>
  `st_crs<-`(st_crs(coordinates.sf))

and loop over ellipses, starting with row number 1
idx = 1L 
for(i in seq(nrow(coordinates.sf))[-1L]) {
  q = length(unlist(sf::st_intersects(coordinates.sf$E$geometry[idx], coordinates.sf$E$geometry[i])))
  if(!q) idx = c(idx, i)
}

Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=coordinates.sf[idx, ]) +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry=E$geometryE), fill="blue", alpha=.2) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label=id)) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="Easting", y="Northing")

gives


Input Data
coordinates.df = data.frame(x = c(611547.6411, 589547.6411, 611447.6411, 609847.6411, 606347.6411, 611447.6411, 613547.6411,642747.6411, 589647.6411, 606447.6411, 613547.6411, 640347.6411, 642847.6411, 612147.6411, 613847.6411, 640247.6411, 642947.6411, 584347.6411, 587747.6411, 606447.6411, 614247.6411, 640447.6411, 642747.6411, 584447.6411, 608647.6411, 612047.6411, 612747.6411,
                                  613847.6411, 643147.6411, 583147.6411, 608747.6411, 611847.6411, 609647.6411, 610047.6411, 613747.6411, 586247.6411, 588647.6411, 643147.6411, 584347.6411, 606447.6411, 610147.6411, 613347.6411, 614647.6411, 586047.6411, 587247.6411, 611547.6411, 640347.6411, 643147.6411, 587147.6411, 583047.6411, 608747.6411, 612047.6411, 613947.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586847.6411, 611247.6411, 643247.6411, 587247.6411, 590347.6411, 582947.6411, 608947.6411, 611847.6411, 613447.6411, 614647.6411, 585147.6411, 587647.6411, 588547.6411, 586947.6411, 611247.6411, 643047.6411, 587147.6411, 583947.6411, 587747.6411, 608547.6411, 611747.6411, 614047.6411, 585247.6411, 586247.6411, 588447.6411, 589147.6411, 611347.6411, 642447.6411, 586947.6411, 585847.6411, 587747.6411, 581447.6411, 612447.6411, 611947.6411, 600547.6411,
                                  612047.6411, 610347.6411, 614147.6411, 582847.6411, 588547.6411, 589247.6411, 611247.6411, 638147.6411, 640547.6411, 642947.6411, 587047.6411, 585947.6411, 587647.6411, 600447.6411, 611347.6411, 612347.6411, 610347.6411, 587747.6411, 579747.6411, 583847.6411, 586847.6411, 588447.6411, 589347.6411, 643347.6411, 589347.6411, 586947.6411, 588247.6411, 588847.6411, 585847.6411, 590847.6411, 589447.6411, 590947.6411, 581347.6411, 611847.6411, 600647.6411, 610347.6411, 615947.6411, 613947.6411, 586347.6411, 579647.6411, 584047.6411, 586347.6411, 587747.6411, 587947.6411, 586547.6411, 587647.6411, 614047.6411, 643047.6411, 587947.6411, 585747.6411, 584947.6411, 600547.6411, 611947.6411, 606847.6411, 600847.6411, 612847.6411, 615747.6411, 620747.6411, 614047.6411, 632947.6411, 588147.6411, 579747.6411, 582747.6411), y = c(5272140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271640.5728, 5267440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271640.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277940.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268140.5728, 5268640.5728, 5271140.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271740.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5271240.5728, 5271340.5728, 5272240.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5277240.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5268540.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5277340.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266840.5728, 5267240.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5272140.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272340.5728, 5277140.5728, 5277240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277740.5728, 5277740.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278240.5728, 5278240.5728, 5264940.5728, 5265040.5728, 5265140.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266840.5728, 5266940.5728, 5267040.5728, 5267140.5728, 5267340.5728, 5267440.5728, 5268340.5728,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            5271240.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271940.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271840.5728, 5271840.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272140.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272340.5728, 5274340.5728, 5274440.5728, 5274640.5728, 5285140.5728, 5285240.5728, 5277340.5728, 5277540.5728, 5277840.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278040.5728, 5278140.5728, 5278140.5728, 5265540.5728, 5265640.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266740.5728, 5266940.5728, 5268340.5728, 5268440.5728, 5271440.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271540.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272040.5728, 5272340.5728, 5271740.5728, 5272240.5728, 5272240.5728, 5274540.5728, 5275040.5728, 5275340.5728, 5284840.5728, 5284940.5728, 5284940.5728, 5285040.5728, 5285040.5728))

coordinates.df$id = seq(nrow(coordinates.df))  # id 
coordinates.df = coordinates.df[c("id", "x", "y")] # re-order 
coordinates.sf = sf::st_as_sf(coordinates.df, coords = c("x", "y"), crs=25832) # create sf-object with crs 


Thanks for the improvements. Since in st_ellipse the radius is requested, I adjusted 700 and 500 to 350 and 250.
